# How to Change Decimal(10,2) datatype to float/double in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to change the type of of a column in mysql. I want to change the datatype from decimal(10,2) to float or double. I went through the different posts on Stackoverflow and tried the following query

```
    ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname float;
```

When I run the Query, it does not complete execution.Please advice.

Comment: How much data do you have in your table?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Ishamae l have 223 columns and 10GB of data.

Comment: @PaulF I do not get any error, but the query remains in the Running state

Answer (score 0):

Alter table in MySQL is not known to be very fast. On a 10GB table it can take a very long while, and your table will not be accessible all that time.

In other words, what you observe is not a hanging alter table, it's a very slow alter table.

One way to address it would be to create a new table with a new schema you want, then to `INSERT ... SELECT` data from the old table into the new table, then drop the old table and rename the new table into the old table. This way your data will be accessible for reads while you are changing the schema. It will technically also accessible for writes, but those writes will be naturally lost when you drop the old table.

There's no way to do an online alter (an `ALTER TABLE` that allows you to read and write into the table while it is being altered) in MySQL.